# Sql Variable PHP Inclusion Issue

Tags: php, sql

Hi I'm having trouble adding a variable to my Sql script, if i replace $safe with 'text' it works fine, i guess its a simple synatax problem.  I hope someone can help as i'm a bit of a newbie!

```
<?
$ORDERID = 'LH-PAY-'.rand(10000000,99999999);
$safe - mysql_escape_string($ORDERID);

mysql_connect("localhost", "youthtra_wp1", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("youthtra_wp1") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO tblPayments (PaymentID,Created,Status,Type,FlgID,WpUser,FullAmount,InsuranceAmount) VALUES ('".$safe."',now(),'Started','edpq','12345678','LH23456','499.99','19.99' )";
mysql_query($query);
echo 'ok';
```

Comment: What happens? Are you getting an error? Try printing `$query` before executing, see what's in there.

Comment: So what happens if you don't replace `$safe`? Do you get a white screen? An error? The wrong data inserted? Some of the right data?

Comment: Fix the `-` on `$safe - mysql...`.

Comment: thanks so much guys - schoolboy error!

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

a) `$safe` is anything but. `mysql_escape_string()` is NOT safe to use. That's why `mysql_real_escape_string()` exists.
b) You shouldn't be using the mysql_*() functions anyways
c) You're simply assuming your query will always succeed, and are deliberately IGNORING the return value of mysql_query() which could help you if/when things fail. e.g. your code should be, at minimum:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the `-` for `=` on line 3:

```
$safe - mysql_escape_string($ORDERID);
```